# Display dialog from android.app.application

Tags: android-activity, android, android-context

I have an update routine (connects to server and looks for a newer version of itself) that runs onCreate on my first activity. If there is an update then a dialog is presented to the user, if update isn't mandatory, asking if they want to download the update.

The problem is that I don't want to run this in the activity as it gets called each time the activity is reloaded, like when device is rotated.

I could create a singleton which knows if the check has already been performed or something similar but would prefer to make the check outside of the activity as it just doesn't seem like the right place to do it.

The problem I have is if I put it in the android.app.application then I have no activity to create the dialog. I could create a loader activity just for this and then fire the main activity after but this also doesn't seem ideal.

What would be a good way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You can't launch an activity from the Application context, sadly it's just not possible. What you need to do is create an activity with

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

within the activity tag in your AndroidManifest.xml. In this activity you should define a fairly simple layout to make it look as much like a dialog as possible (or not if you want it to look like something else).

Another option is to have your first activity setup a BroadcastReceiver and then have the Application context

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("MyUniqueID"));
```

Within the onReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver display your dialog with the Activity context.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? I should perform the checkForUpdate() inside the Application context. This will create an AsyncTask to connect to the server and check for the update, then in the onPostExecute, if an update does exist, start a new activity with sendBroadcast using the Application contact. This activity will be pushed over my main activity and present a dialog (Due to the activity formatting) to the user. In that activity if they press "update" then kick off a new AsynTask to download the update. The Dialog activity would then die, but I could do the update in the 2nd AsyncTask

Comment: Ideally I don't want to put this inside the main activity because if the network connection is not very good, I could kick off the connection to the server for update and by the time it returns the Activity that started it could have been destroyed. Also if the calling code is inside an activity it will end up being called multiple times as the user navigates around the application so I really don't think it is right to put this sort of check inside the apps main activity.

Comment: @Mark You don't actually start a new activity if an update exists, you just send a broadcast to your activity so the activity's context can display the dialog. The 2 methods I posted above shouldn't be used together, you should use 1 method or the other.

Answer (score 0):

crdnilfan has given good answer.and if you want to do it in your MainActivity,then you can maintain Activity Lifecycle in proper manner like described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)
and if you want to restrict to call `onCreate()` whenever you rotate your device,you can specify configChanges,

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.temp.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I hope it will be helpful !!